# Excel Conditional Formatting Dates

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a column A of text (not dates), and I would like it to be filled in with colour when the cell beside it in column B has the same date as today.

I have tried to use these formulae in Conditional Formatting:

=IF($B:$B = TODAY())

=IF(B:B = TODAY())

This was applied to the whole A column, and a fill colour was selected, but nothing happened.

Not sure if the formula is the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my attachment. You just need `=$B1=TODAY()` on the first cell and drag it down to cover the whole column and that should do the trick for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, this gets the job done!
Unfortunately my upvote doesn't count with my reputation score!

Answer (score 0):

While you are typing the formula, you need to use the reference for the field the cursor is currently in.

So when you select the whole column A, one of the cells is still the 'current' cell (probably A1). Write your formula for A1, using relative addressing, and Excel will apply it respectively to all other selected cells (all of A), like `=IF(B1=TODAY())`.

Note that `B1` is a *relative* reference, and is interpreted relative to `A1`, so for `A2`, `B2` will used in the comparison. If you would want an *absolute* reference, you would need to add a $ sign in the absolute part, for example `=IF(B$1=TODAY())` would color *all* cells according to the value in `B1`.

Comment: Thanks very much, this detail will help me properly understand Excel! Again sorry the upvote doesn't count with my reputation score.